# Fetching mongodb one by one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection named Questions.

I want to fetch first question, then when user clicks a button, give him the next..

So i'm fetching the first item like this:

```
Template.home.user_questions = function () {
 return Questions.find({}, {sort: {answer1:{'$ne': ''}}, limit: 1});
}
```

And I'm getting the user's click like this:

```
'click input' : function () {
  Questions.update(this._id, {$inc: {value1: 1}})
  // now show him next item
}
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to show the next item since I hasNext() and next() methods are not supported by meteor

Comment: I'm unclear what the rules of the game are. Do I show the user the next question that has an answer that he/she has not yet seen? If so, should that persist across sessions? Should I never see the same question again?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't clear enough. Indeed, the user should not see a question he already saw, and it should persist across sessions (I haven't though about it yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `skip`.

```
Template.home.user_questions = function () {
    var skip = Session.get("skip") || 0;
    return Questions.find({}, {sort: {answer1:{'$ne': ''}}, limit: 1, skip: skip});
}
```

Then when you want to move to the next question, augment the session value of skip by 1. e.g

```
Session.set("skip", (Session.get("skip") || 0) ++);
```

This should reactively move to the next question, up to the last.

Comment: Using sessions, nice thinking ;) I got on the other hand an error on the Session.set() line : `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` and had to replace the `++` by an `+ 1` to get it to work